# Differences between the approaches to writing applications in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I wonder what are the differences in the approach to creating web applications in spring boot, namely I have two variants of my project and I wonder which one will be more suitable:

**Frist:**

In the first variant I have:

**Controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/articles")
public class ArticlesController {


@Autowired
private ArticlesRepository articlesRepository;


@GetMapping
public List<Articles> list(){
    return articlesRepository.findAll();
}

@GetMapping
@RequestMapping("{id}")
public Articles get(@PathVariable Long id) {
    return articlesRepository.getOne(id);
}}
```

**Reposiotry:**

```
public interface ArticlesRepository extends JpaRepository<Articles,Long> {
}
```

**Model:**

```
@Entity(name="articles")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Articles {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long article_id;
private String title;
private String issn;
private String eissn;
private String title2;
private String issn2;
private String eissn2;
private Integer points;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
    name = "articles_categories",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "article_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"))
private List<Category> categories;
 ....

getters and setters
```

For now this approach returns data in json format. Additional question: is it possible to use thymeleaf here?

**Second:**

In the second variant I have:

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/articles")
public class ArticlesController {


private ArticleService articleService;

@Autowired
public void setArticleService(ArticleService articleService) {
    this.articleService = articleService;
}

@GetMapping
public String getAll(Model model)
{
    model.addAttribute("articles", articleService.list());
    return "articles";
}
}
```

**Repository:**

```
public interface ArticlesRepository extends JpaRepository<Articles,Long> {
}
```

**Service:**

```
@Service
public class ArticleService {


@Autowired
private ArticlesRepository articlesRepository;

public ArticleService() {
}

public List<Articles> list(){
    return articlesRepository.findAll();
}


public Articles get(Long id) {
    return articlesRepository.getOne(id);
}


}
```

Model class is the same as in the first approach. In the second approach I use thymeleaf template here.

Comment: Service classes are generally added when you would like to add some business logic or do some transformations. Which approach to follow depends on what is your use case and what you prefer. Neither one of them is more suitable than the other.

Comment: Ok, I undestand. How can I use thymeleaf in the first attempt to display all records? Is it possible?

Comment: That's a too generic question in my view. If you are trying to enquire whether you can loop through array/list in thymeleaf, it's possible. You can refer [this](https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-iteration) article for reference.

Comment: what should my controller method return in this case?shouldn't it be the name of the html template?

Comment: The method can have either of two: 1) `Spring` - Returns template name 2) `ModelAndView` - Returns view name and model data

Comment: So, for example this method: `@GetMapping
public List<Articles> list(){
    return articlesRepository.findAll();
}` should be change?

Comment: Yes, something like `public ModelAndView list() { ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("listAllPage"); mav.addObject("articlesList", articlesRepository.findAll()); return mav;}`

Comment: I would recommend you to refer articles available on the internet for learning. Stackoverflow is not the correct place for that. :)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I learn a lot from the internet,now I wanted to make sure about it because I was confused by the multitude of Internet knowledge.